# Is there any way to write a non-local operator nicely?

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, non-locality

Consider the boundary(the real axis) of the 2d CFT or the D-brane. They were non local object but with well known description.
Consider the following expression,

$$\langle 0| \phi_1(z_1) \phi_2(z_2)|B\rangle\rangle$$

where $|B\rangle\rangle$ stands for the boundary and the $\phi_i(z)$ were the bulk fields. However, if $z_1$ and $z_2$ were pulled apart in the imaginary "$y$" direction but still close to the non local boundary. The following equation should be equivalent to

$$\lim_{\text{Im}(z_1-z_2)\rightarrow \infty}
\langle 0| \phi_1(z_1) \phi_2(z_2)|B\rangle\rangle
=
\lim_{\text{Im}(z_1-z_2)\rightarrow \infty}
\langle 0| \phi_1(z_1) |B\rangle\rangle\langle 0|\phi_2(z_2)|B\rangle\rangle$$

(my advisor) which was obvious but algebraically this seemed to say that the insertion of the operation
$$\lim_{\text{Im}(z_1-z_2)\rightarrow \infty} |B\rangle\rangle\langle 0|=1$$

This bothered a bit. Is there any way to write a non local operator nicely?(not hand waving)

Comment: 1. No, your equation does not imply that $\lim_{\mathrm{Im}{z_1 - z_2}\to \infty} \lvert B\rangle\langle 0\rvert = 1$ - that equation doesn't make sense because $\lvert B\rangle\langle 0\rvert$ doesn't depend on the $z_i$ at all. 2. What is "the boundary (the real axis) of the 2d CFT"? Plenty of CFTs don't have boundaries. What is the "well-known description" you are referring to? Are you talking about Ishibashi states? 3. Is the equation where you're "pulling apart" the operators not simply [cluster decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decomposition)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. i felt so because $|B\rangle\rangle \langle 0|$ looked like an interface and even in that language it's not complete, but how to systematically insert the non local operator which might lead to the expression such as $|B\rangle\rangle \langle 0|$ then? because the second line they were equal 2. Here it's CFT with the present of boundary, where boundary was non local. CFT bulk operators were local operators and was not the case of the interest. $|B\rangle\rangle$ was the physical boundary states, not just the Ishibashi states. 3. It can be viewed as a cluster decomposition. but

Comment: @ACuriousMind how can we write it more nicely? (thank you. the 3. was very useful) From a mathematical point of the view, every time I looked at that equation(the second line) I found it bothering, and yet there might be infinitely many of those. It would be nice if those non local operations could be written more systematically, because the "cluster decomposition" was almost the definition of "non local" operator in essence.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Cluster decomposition says that $\langle \mathcal{O}(x_1)\mathcal{O}(x_2)\rangle = \langle \mathcal{O}(x_1)\rangle\langle\mathcal{O}(x_2)\rangle$ as $\lvert x_1 - x_2\rvert \to\infty$. What more do you need?